# Why is Ubuntu's main search feature so ineffective?

Tags: unity, files, search

At least for me it is.

When I click on the **Search your computer and online sources** icon in the top left corner and type a file I want to find, and type a file, for example for me, *Casino Royale*, it will just look up stuff online, so I then have to go to filters and click on **Files and Folders**.

One would think this would do the trick and it would easily find the file. Nope. It brings up the Downloads file icon, so I click on it, and the file I want isn't even there, it has a similar file (Live and Let Die movie that I've downloaded to that folder).

The file I was looking for is an a completely different folder.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this normal or is it somehow specific to my system? Have I set up something wrong?
2. Is there actually a way to find the files I'm after, without using the command prompt which I do not want to use?

Comment: Do you find the file search in Nautilus any more effective?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: The default file manager is called "Nautilus" and it has a search facility.

Comment: The first question can't really be answered. More of a complaint. Nothing wrong with that, but AskUbuntu is not the place for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off the online search in your <kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd> → <kbd>Search</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: That does not help. I look up files (movie titles) that i know are on my computer, and for whatever reason Ubuntu's search program (top left corner) cannot find them. Id have to rate Ubuntu's search feature a 0 and give that aspect as a win for Windows and loss for Ubuntu.

Comment: @MartinWilson The Unity Dash's Files&Folders lens is really not a great searching tool, I have to admit. You can open your file manager (nautilus) and use its search bar instead. Or maybe you find a nice front-end for the `find`-command. I could also maybe code one if that doesn't already exist when I have time... Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've figured it out. I went to Files on left hand side and typed file name in search bar to bring up the file i wanted.

Comment: Oh, you found Nautilus then, it's the icon called Files that you describe.

Comment: What you mention is the Files manager a.k.a. `nautilus`.